# ISP without reverse DNS - about spamers

Tags: dns, spam

Is it all legitimate ISPs have reverse DNS record?

Is it make sense to block any visitors if their internet service providers have no reverse DNS?

Comment: This is blatantly off topic

Answer (score 0):

Reverse DNS records (PTR records) are not required.  The vast majority of legitimate IP addresses do not have PTR records.